# is there a workaround to allow Active Reports to run under Win10 OS?

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration, activereports

I am supporting a legacy VB6 Desktop program that uses Active Reports to create a lot of reports and many of them are exported to Excel.

There are many users still using Windows XP. More and more users are switching to Windows 10

I have gotten the VB6 programs installed successfully on the Windows 10 Machines. The Active Reports works fine for everything, except when a Win10 user attempts to export a report to Excel from the ARViewer control. It gives an error 9 and quits. Do you know of a workaround or have you encountered this problem yourself?

Comment: Error 9 was created by a programmer called Bill Gates. _Subscript out of range
See Also
UBound Function | LBound Function | Dim Statement | ReDim Statement
The array you are trying to access contains fewer elements than you expect. For example, attempting to access the 11th element of an array dimensioned for ten elements.

To correct this error 

Make sure your code contains bounds checking that ensures elements beyond the scope of the array are not referenced. 
Re-dimension the array to a larger size that meets your needs_

Comment: I'm supporting Active Reports on Windows 10 machines. We export to Excel just fine so I suspect you need to investigate the error. Are you setting the `Version` property when you export and if so, to what?

Comment: I think you should add some specific details, like the specific code that errors out

Answer (score 0):

You can get 9 (Subscript out of range) error if your arv.Pages.Count=0. This is why the example code contains a check for the page count. See [ActiveReports 2 Exports](https://help.grapecity.com/activereports/webhelp/Legacy/AR2Exports/AR2Exports_start.htm)

```
Private Sub mEExpt_Click()
    Dim xls As New ActiveReportsExcelExport.ARExportExcel
    Dim sFile As String

    sFile = "c:\activereports\vbexport\test1.xls"
    xls.FileName = sFile
    If arv.Pages.Count > 0 Then
        xls.Export arv.Pages
    End If
End Sub
```